# Why EtBr migrate toward the opposite direction？

Tags: molecular-biology

We known that DNA would run toward the positive electrode, because of they have negative electricity. then why EtBr migrate toward the opposite direction to DNA?
is because they have positive electricity?

Comment: EtBr runs the same direction as DNA. If it runs the wrong way, you probably have your red wires on top (mixed up)

Answer (score 1):

Ethidium bromide itself is neutral in charge, however in aqueous environment it's a positive ion and it travels towards the negative electrode, opposite to DNA, as DNA is negatively charged and travels towards the positive electrode.

The thing is, it doesn't matter all that much. Whether you prepare a gel with EtBr added or you add EtBr to the electrophoresis buffer, it will instantly start intercalating the moment you insert your sample or start running the gel. The moment the electric current is applied, EtBr will indeed start migrating towards the negative electrode but some finite amount would have already intercalated into the DNA and it's going to be visible under UV only when bound to DNA. Keep that in mind that EtBr is a much smaller molecule and penetrates the gel easily, but will get trapped in between DNA base pairs if it happens to find some.

With that said, as one of the commenters pointed out, if your samples seem to have travelled the other way around, you have probably swapped the cables. The charge of the electrode depends on the charge applied by the source of electric current and if you mistake the cables, you will actually make the samples travel towards the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Negatively charged anions migrate towards the anode electrode during electrophoresis.  Likewise, positively charged cations migrate towards the cathode electrode in electrophoresis.  Neutral molecules, lacking any net charge whatsoever will remain immobilized in the loading wells.  The net charge on a molecule in an aqueous buffer depends on the both the molecular structure, and the pH of the buffer.  If you agree with all of these facts, then you have answered your own question.